# Why can't I use my old username for my new account on GitHub

Tags: github

I recently changed my Github username for one of my accounts and now I want to use back that old username for another new account. However, Github tells me that the username is still in use even though I have successfully changed everything for my original account. Could someone help me?

Comment: You'd have to talk to GitHub support, I'd guess they hold the old username to prevent someone else registering it and pretending to be you.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Ahh I see, cause I read somewhere online that they will let go of the old username after some time. I guess I have no choice then, thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

> When you delete your account we stop billing you. The email address associated with the account becomes available for use with a different account on GitHub.com. After 90 days, the account name also becomes available to anyone else to use on a new account.

https://docs.github.com/en/account-and-profile/setting-up-and-managing-your-github-user-account/managing-user-account-settings/deleting-your-user-account

Comment: Maybe if you contact support they can help you out if you can prove your identity.